# Missing $ or } in split environment and I can't find the source of the error

Tags: equations

I simply can't find the error in my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{todonotes} 
\usepackage{kbordermatrix} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy} 
\usepackage{multirow}


\newcommand{\bg}{\boldsymbol{g}}
\newcommand{\bh}{\boldsymbol{h}}
    \begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{split}
    U((1:n), (n-1:n))=\left[ U \cdot I_{n}\right]((1:n), (n-1:n))=U((1:n),(n-1:n))
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \cdots & 0 &  0 &  1
    \end{pmatrix} \\
    =\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c|c}
           0 & \cdots & 0 & \multirow{2}{*}{\bh_{n-1}}      &  \multirow{2}{*}{B_{n}\bh_n} \\ 
           0 & \cdots & 0 &   \\
    \end{array} \right) =
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    G_{n-1}h_{n-1} & G_{n-1}B_n \\ \sigma_{n-1} &  \bg_n^T 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{split}
    \]


\end{document}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
```

Comment: Thanks for editing egreg, no idea what happend to the format. :)

Comment: Why don't you add `\documentclass...` and `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}`. So we can compile it.

Comment: The material in `\multirow` is not in math by default. But I don't think you need it.

Comment: Ok, I tried to edit it but it so you can compile the code... changed my format again.. Sorry :/

Comment: I added the multirow package just recently for the cmd \multirow {<number>}{*}{<value>}

Answer (score 2):

The material in `\multirow` will not start in math mode even if `\multirow` is found in `array` rather than `tabular`. So it should be

```
\multirow{2}{*}{$\bh_{n-1}$}
```

But you don't need it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\bh}{\bm{\chi}}
\newcommand{\bg}{\bm{\gamma}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
U((1:n), (n-1:n))
  &= [U \cdot I_{n}]((1:n), (n-1:n))\\
  &= U((1:n),(n-1:n))
     \begin{pmatrix} 
     0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1
     \end{pmatrix} \\
  &= \left(\begin{array}{@{}c|c|c@{}}
       \begin{matrix}
       0 & \cdots & 0 \\
       0 & \cdots & 0
       \end{matrix} &
       \bh_{n-1} & B_{n}\bh_n
     \end{array} \right) \\
  &= \begin{pmatrix} 
     G_{n-1}h_{n-1} & G_{n-1}B_n \\
     \sigma_{n-1} &  \bg_n^T 
     \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note the `@{}` in `array` in order to emulate `amsmath`'s matrices. Just use a `matrix` inside the `array`.

Some words about your code.

- Never pass `[pdftex]` to `graphicx`
- Don't load `amsbsy`, but rather `bm` and use its `\bm` command instead of `\boldsymbol`.
- You have a `\left`-`\right` pair that's useless (but that leaves an unwanted space).

I've guessed the definitions of `\bg` and `\bh`. Use your own, of course, but with `\bm`.

[image]

Comment: You sir, have made my day. I will work out the things you said.
Why is the package bm preferred to amsbsy?

Comment: @Robert Try `texdoc amsbsy`; if you don't know how to do it on your system, click the following link: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.pdf